# Percentage of Ramanujan's conjectures that were proven correct

Tags: ho.history-overview, conjectures, ramanujan

Today I read the following brief but insightful account of Ramanujan's approach to mathematics: https://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/images/KSRchap3.pdf and while reading this I wondered whether we have a lower-bound on the percentage of Ramanujan's conjectures which are correct.

I'm planning to get a copy of Ramanujan's notebooks. Meanwhile, the above question intrigues me.

Comment: Side question, are there conjectures of him still open?

Comment: Dual question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288410/what-did-ramanujan-get-wrong/288412

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This interview with Prof. Bruce Berndt](https://web.archive.org/web/20130925201456/http://www.frontline.in/static/html/fl1617/16170810.htm) indicates the percentage of correct results from his notebooks to be greater than 99.7%. (See also this [longer writeup.](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/articles/aachen.pdf))

> Between 1903 and 1914, before Ramanujan went to Cambridge, he compiled
>   3,542 theorems in the notebooks. I have gone through every entry in
>   the notebooks. If a result has already been proved in the literature,
>   then I just wrote the entry down and said that proofs can be found in
>   this literature and so on.There are a number of misprints. I did not
>   count the number of serious mistakes but it is an extremely small
>   number - maybe five or ten out of over 3,000 results. Considering that
>   Ramanujan did not have any rigorous training, it is really amazing
>   that he made so few mistakes.

[Bruce Berndt, Ramanujan's Notebooks, parts I--V.](https://www.springer.com/series/741)

*side question:* The [Ramanujan–Petersson conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Petersson_conjecture) for Maass forms is still open.

Comment: Of course the Ramanujan-Petersson conjecture for Maas forms is not actually Ramanujan's per se.

Comment: Do you really mean 0.997%? I guess that should read 99.7% of correct theorems.

Comment: thank you @ManfredWeis , for correcting my silly typo.

Comment: "really amazing" - is that one of those understatements mathematicians are fond of?