# Which W W Sawyer titles exist in non-English language editions?

Tags: mathematics-education

In [this community question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309650/what-are-examples-of-books-which-teach-the-practice-of-mathematics) asking about books that teach the practice of mathematics, the author mentions the works of [W W Sawyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Warwick_Sawyer).

Which of Sawyer's books were translated into languages other than English, and what are the publication details?

His [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Warwick_Sawyer) states that his books *Mathematician's Delight* and *Prelude to Mathematics* "have been translated into many languages", but I have been unable to find publication details for any non-English language edition of even a single book of his. The cited source is an article by Ailsa Ferguson published by the University of Toronto (thanks, @Igor Khavkine, for tracking this down at Archive.org) which states that *MD* was translated into 10 languages and *PtM* into six, but that's all I know at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried searching on non-English language Amazon sites?

Comment: The article by Ferguson is in the Way Back Machine, but is also scant on the details. https://web.archive.org/web/20160502065642/http://news.utoronto.ca/sawyer-was-dedicated-teacher-educator

Comment: @JeremyRickard - Yes. His author number at Amazon is B001ITYQIY. That company's [.es](https://www.amazon.es/W-W-Sawyer/e/B001ITYQIY?), [.fr](https://www.amazon.fr/W-W-Sawyer/e/B001ITYQIY?), [.de](https://www.amazon.de/W-W-Sawyer/e/B001ITYQIY?) and [.it](https://www.amazon.it/W-W-Sawyer/e/B001ITYQIY?) sites only list works by him in the original English.

Comment: Many thanks for this, @IgorKhavkine. Ferguson may not identify specific languages, but she does say that *Mathematician's Delight* was translated into 10 and *Prelude to Mathematics* into six, giving grounds for confidence that his works were indeed much translated.

Comment: This is more of a question for Academia stackexchange than for this forum.  You should be able to access WorldCat and similar catalogues to find out this information. Searching by published by and author combination sounds promising.  Gerhard "Consult Your Local Librarian (Distantly)" Paseman, 2020.06.09.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman - His best-known titles weren't academic. Searching on "W W Sawyer" at WorldCat.com brings up some of his titles but only in English. What similar catalogues do you recommend? The WorldCat engine has no "published by" field, but even if it did I have no idea who published any non-English language editions.

Comment: Using Wikipedia and the ISBN link in the article on Sawyer, within minutes I found the Karlsruhe Virtueller Katalog, which is an interface to many European catalog systems, and includes WorldCat. Using Prelude to Mathematics, I found links to catalog entries in five different languages, indicating at least five different language versions.  I recommend you try this path.  Gerhard "Check Out The Search Fields" Paseman, 2020.06.09.

Comment: Many thanks, @GerhardPaseman. Please can you post a link to your search that indicates "at least five" non-English editions of *Prelude to Mathematics*. (That would look good in an answer, but if the URL is long then it still might fit in a comment if you choose not to write your name redundantly when it is there in your handle anyway, or if you do want it to be displayed twice then not to insert a humorous middle moniker.)

Comment: Searching for "WW Sawyer" on amazon.fr I found several French translations of his books. Also a handful of foreign translations on the .it, .de, .es., .nl and .jp sites (although on the Spanish site it first gave me results on professional wrestling and I had to assure it that I really did mean "WW Sawyer" and not "WWE Sawyer").

Comment: Thanks for this, @JeremyRickard. After typing "W W Sawyer" in inverted commas as the search term, I've now found the following at amazon.fr: *Plaisir de Mathématiques*, *Voir et Comprendre les Mathématiques*, and *Introduction aux Mathématiques*. Did you find any Spanish editions? On amazon.es I found Dutch, French, and Italian, but no Spanish.

Comment: No, no Spanish. I thought there was one on the .es site, but I wasn’t paying attention: it was Italian.

Answer (score 1):

The Polish Wikipedia page of W W Sawyer lists titles of the translations (with some publication details) of his books into Polish, but not the original titles (Mathematicians' Delight seems to be Matematyka Nauka Przyjemna; I don't have a copy at hand to confirm). Some of these translations had multiple editions; covers can be seen here: https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=W+W+Sawyer+matematyka&client=firefox-b&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDscvv7PXpAhUS2qwKHdOLBe8QsAR6BAgIEAE&biw=1588&bih=713

Answer (score 1):

As requested here is the URL for the search results.

https://kvk.bibliothek.kit.edu/hylib-bin/kvk/nph-kvk2.cgi?maske=kvk-redesign&lang=en&title=KIT-Bibliothek%3A+Karlsruher+Virtueller+Katalog+KVK+%3A+Ergebnisanzeige&head=%2F%2Fkvk.bibliothek.kit.edu%2Fasset%2Fhtml%2Fhead.html&header=%2F%2Fkvk.bibliothek.kit.edu%2Fasset%2Fhtml%2Fheader.html&spacer=%2F%2Fkvk.bibliothek.kit.edu%2Fasset%2Fhtml%2Fspacer.html&footer=%2F%2Fkvk.bibliothek.kit.edu%2Fasset%2Fhtml%2Ffooter.html&css=none&input-charset=utf-8&ALL=&TI=Prelude+to+mathematics&AU=Sawyer&CI=&ST=&PY=&SB=&SS=&PU=&kataloge=BVB&kataloge=SWISSBIB&kataloge=WORLDCAT&ref=direct&client-js=yes

Note that I chose only a few catalogues out of the many that the KVK interface offers. Worldcat yielded many references.  I recommend you try your own searches using your own catalogue choices.

Gerhard "Internet Catalogues Offer The World" Paseman, 2020.06.10.

Comment: My signatures serve a purpose to me.  If they do not serve you, don't read them.  (I resisted the temptation to post all but the last few characters of the URL.) Gerhard "You're Welcome For The Link" Paseman, 2020.06.10.