# Recommendations for mathematical essayists

Tags: soft-question

I was wondering if people had recommendations for mathematical essays (by this I mean essays on a mathematical topic, not necessarily essays written by mathematicians).

A person who I used to find entertaining to read at high school was Isaac Asimov, although for some reason he did not write many essays on pure mathematics.  In particular I remember the essay collection *X Stands for Unknown*, which had several entertaining mathematics essays, most of them with a combinatorial flavour if I remember rightly.

Comment: there is an extensive list at https://mathoverflow.net/q/220052/11260

Comment: Martin Gardner, maybe?  But does this question belong to Mathoverflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gian-Carlo Rota wrote beautifully and widely, my personal favourite.

Answer (score 1):

Ed Sandifer and his column in AMM "[How Euler Did It](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/)" ("HEDI").